# Pandas: Replace and append entire list in a bigger pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, replace

I have a pandas data frame which looks like this

```
URLs          | Feature1 | Feature2  | Feature3
yahoo.com     | nan      | nan       | nan 
economist.com | nan      | nan       | nan 
facebook.com  | nan      | nan       | nan
```

I am calculating the features through a user-defined-function that takes the URLs one by one to analyze and return the features in a list format.

I loop through the dataset to calculate features. The first iteration returns, say [1,2,3] for yahoo; [9,10,0] for economist and [0,8,10] for facebook.

My question is, within the loop, how to do I attach the list to the dataframe so that with each iteration it looks like this

```
URLs          | Feature1 | Feature2  | Feature3
yahoo.com     | 1        | 2         | 3 
economist.com | nan      | nan       | nan 
facebook.com  | nan      | nan       | nan
```

and then with the next iteration

```
URLs          | Feature1 | Feature2  | Feature3
yahoo.com     | 1        | 2         | 3 
economist.com | 9        | 10        | 0 
facebook.com  | nan      | nan       | nan
```

and finally,

```
URLs          | Feature1 | Feature2  | Feature3
yahoo.com     | 1        | 2         | 3 
economist.com | 9        | 10        | 0 
facebook.com  | 0        | 8         | 10
```

which is the answer I want to store.

Permutations of `list.append` or `pandas.replace` didn't lead me anywhere. I couldn't find questions where people were doing something like this. Or maybe I am not sure how to word my search. Any help is super appreciated.

Comment: you can append those values in a list then make dataframe of it and then assign back

Comment: @AnuragDabas So there is no direct peel and paste sort of a thing for this, right? I will have to go the long way?

Comment: you can use `.loc` accessor inside the for loop to assign that back it is the direct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .apply to run the function on every row and return the values to the relevant columns

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([["yahoo.com", None, None, None], ["economist.com", None, None, None], ["facebook.com", None, None, None]], colum
   ...: ns=["URLs", "Feature1", "Feature2", "Feature3"])

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
            URLs Feature1 Feature2 Feature3
0      yahoo.com     None     None     None
1  economist.com     None     None     None
2   facebook.com     None     None     None

In [4]: def some_func(url):
   ...:     if url == "yahoo.com":
   ...:         return 1, 2, 3
   ...:     if url == "economist.com":
   ...:         return 9, 10, 0
   ...:     return 0, 8, 10
   ...:

In [5]: df[['Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3']] = df.apply(lambda row: some_func(row['URLs']), axis=1, result_type='expand')

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
            URLs  Feature1  Feature2  Feature3
0      yahoo.com         1         2         3
1  economist.com         9        10         0
2   facebook.com         0         8        10
```